# Shopify API: How do I get API schema changes?

Tags: api, shopify

We have a custom integration that uses Shopify API. Changes to the schema breaks the integration. Today we have found The field `Source` has been removed and 3 fields have been added in its place: *source_identifier* , *source_name* and *source_url*. (orders api)

Is there a way to get information on coming changes, so we can be pro-active, rather than waiting for our integration to break in production and look for the changes while our fulfillment service waits?

Comment: Be nice if you could point out which API method changed exactly. The spelling is break and not brake :) To break something means to wreck it, whereas to brake usually refers to a slowing/stopping a moving vehicle.

Comment: Thanks for the spelling lesson! I did get a response stating that removal of the Source field was a mistake.  Since the API does not support versioning, it would be helpful to get an update notice or newsletter with upcoming changes, date and time and final results, so we could expect possible interruption in our integrations.

Comment: Well keeping an eye on http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology and http://www.shopify.com/blog/tagged/announcements would be one way …

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never ;) I suggest you checkout the API Accouncements topic in the Shopify forum, as that is where all important API changes are posted:

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/api-announcements

Note: You can subscribe to the topic, so whenever something new is posted you'll automatically get an email notification.